# fast way to find find min/max/avg value in file

Tags: php

I have a file in the format

```
1    52
2    456
3    4516
5    4545
6     41
```

what would be the fastest way to read in the file and get the min/max/avg value in the second column in PHP?

Comment: PHP already has something to parse files by line....it's a function called... `file()`

That said, @mellamokb's solution is pretty sweet, it solves parsing as well splitting the file outside PHP code, hence it should be faster than a purely PHP one.

Comment: what is the size of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following, where `<filename>` is the path to the file.

```
$file = fopen('<filename>', 'r');

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$first = true;
while (fscanf($file, '%d%d', $a, $b)) {
    if ($first)
    {
        $min = $b;
        $max = $b;
        $total = $b;
        $count = 1;
        $first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $total += $b;
        if ($b < $min) $min = $b;
        if ($b > $max) $max = $b;
        $count++;
    }
}
$avg = $total / $count;
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/rWbqm

Comment: It was giving me "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated" is it ok if I remove the &?

Comment: If I do it gives me "undefined variable a"

Comment: @user391986: Ah, yes I believe you can. You might have to preset `$a` and `$b` to default values.  See update.  Also added example how to open a file with [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen)

Comment: Thanks! how can I handle the case where it would be decimals (first or second value) how do I change the regex

Comment: @user391986: You would use `%f` format specifier instead of `%d` to read a decimal value.  See docs on [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).  Note that these are not regexes, but format strings, two completely different things.  Here's an example that incorporates decimal values: http://ideone.com/FYC3m

Comment: A slight improvement would be to set the `$min` and `$max` to the values of the first line of the file instead of 0 and 999999. Also set the value of `$total` to this value

Comment: Updated with @EdHeal's excellent suggestion of setting the initial values from the first row of data.

Answer (score 1):

Made some performance improvements from @mellamokb code:

```
$file = fopen('<filename>', 'r'); 

$a = $b = 0; 
if (fscanf($file, '%d%d', $a, $b))
{
   $min = $max = $total = $b; 
   $count = 1;
   while (fscanf($file, '%d%d', $a, $b))
   { 
      $total += $b; 
      if ($b < $min) $min = $b; 
      else if ($b > $max) $max = $b; 
      ++$count; 
   } 
   $avg = $total / $count;
}
else
{
   // Do something here as there is nothing in the file
}
```

Comment: Performance improvements?  Looks functionally the same, albeit a little more concise. Unless `if ($first)` is a lot slower operation than I thought ;-)

Comment: Saves on the `if $first` each line after the first. Also skips the check if it has found a new minimum. It depends on the size of the file I suppose.