# PHP - dynamic arguments and dynamic variables

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to use fscanf to read the CSV file to determine the minimum and maximum values. My [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126875/php-determine-minimum-and-maximum-of-all-csv-columns) question gives an overview of what am actually trying to do. I am trying to use fscanf to find the maximum and minimum of CSV columns as below.

```
$file = fopen('<filename>', 'r');

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$first = true;
while (fscanf($file, '%d%d', $a, $b)) {
    if ($first)
    {
        $min = $b;
        $max = $b;
        $total = $b;
        $count = 1;
        $first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $total += $b;
        if ($b < $min) $min = $b;
        if ($b > $max) $max = $b;
        $count++;
    }
}
$avg = $total / $count;
```

For my scenario, I get a CSV file dynamically. I want to use the above code based on the number of columns. For example, if I have 4 columns, I need to use the previous code as,

```
while (fscanf($file, '%d%d%d%d', $a, $b, $c, $d)) {
```

and determine the maximum and minimum values for all the 4 columns in the CSV file. If it is only 3 columns, I need to use the code as,

```
while (fscanf($file, '%d%d%d', $a, $b, $c)) {
```

and determine the maximum and minimum values for all the 3 columns in the CSV file. Is there any way to do this in PHP? Someone please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: As a quick tip, you might check out PHP's fgetcsv function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php - which reads each line into an array. This might be helpful as you could then use array arithmetic functions like max - http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php - and min.

Answer (score 0):

If you only pass two parameters to [`fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php), it will return the parsed values as an array, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$colCount = getColumnCount ($file);  //left as an exercise
$pattern = str_repeat ('%d', $colCount);
while ($values = fscanf ($file, $pattern)) {
  ...
}
```

I've formulated the `$pattern` as you described, but you may need to match that to the format of your CSV file. If your file uses comma delimiters, for example, your pattern might need to look like `str_repeat("%d,", $colCount)` instead.

Comment: I have made the changes as you had suggested. However, I am not able to use that variable inside my program. For example, if we have just 2 columns, the while loop would be while(fscanf($file,%d%d,$a,$b)). To auto generate %d and variable names only I am using two more variables as $pattern and $pattern1. However, I am not able to use the variable name in the program. If I use the variable name produced by $pattern1, I am not able to see any output.

Comment: If you're following my suggestion, the while statement should not look like `while(fscanf($file,%d%d,$a,$b))`. It should look like `while($values = fscanf($file,'%d%d'))` and then you would find the matched column values at `$values[0]` and `$values[1]` inside the loop.