# jQuery Simple Slider with minimum and maximum values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider

I am new to PHP and scripting languages. I am trying to set a slider with the minimum and maximum values for the slider. I want the minimum and maximum values to be displayed even when I move the slider. This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php     
$i = 1;
while (++$i <= $_SESSION['totalcolumns']) {
    $range = $_SESSION["min-column-$i"] . ',' . $_SESSION["max-column-$i"];
    echo '<input type="text"
                 data-slider="true"
                 data-slider-range="', $range, '"
                 data-slider-step="1"/>';
}
?>
```

The above code displays the slider like below.

[image: img]

In the above piece of code, I tried adding the below piece of lines hoping that the minimum and maximum values would get displayed.

```
data-slider-min = "',$_SESSION["min-column-$i"],'" 
data-slider-max = "',$_SESSION["max-column-$i"], '"
```

However, the above lines do not display the minimum and maximum values in the left and right side of the slider. I believe these values are set using javascript (the range values for the slider). This is the javascript code I have so far.

```
<script>
$("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
        .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
        .html(data.value.toFixed(3));
    });
</script>
```

Can someone please let me know how can I display the minimum and maximum values on the left and right side of the sliders?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the jQuery Simple Slider. What you want to do is not currently supported, but there is an outstanding feature request for it. Your only option at this point is to fork the code on GitHub and add the feature if you need it right now. https://github.com/loopj/jquery-simple-slider

Comment: If this is JQuery Simple Slider, than this should work. Look at [their demos](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html). Range feature implemented and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First place inside css this style:

```
[class^=slider] { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 30px; }
.range, .output {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Than you need to modify your javascript to this one:

```
<script>
    $("[data-slider]")
        .each(function () {
            var range;
            var input = $(this);
            $("<span>").addClass("output")
                .insertAfter(input);
            range = input.data("slider-range").split(",");
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[0])
                .insertBefore(input);
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[1])
                .insertAfter(input);
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this).nextAll(".output:first")
                .html(data.value.toFixed(2));
        });
</script>
```

After this slider will look like at this screenshot:
[image: JQuery-Simple-Slider]
**PS**: For this example used code and **data.csv** from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126875/determine-minimum-and-maximum-of-all-csv-columns).

<del>**Update**: Full code of this example: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/aqJ2PZir)</del>.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am able to see the min and max values successfully. However, I am not able to see the range and max value in the same line as the min value.

Comment: For example, i am not getting the output as in the screenshot. But, I am getting it as 10 7.00 in the second line rather than the first line of 3 itself.

Comment: Check <!DOCTYPE> tag. Then check for latest version of **simple-slider.css**, **simple-slider-volume.css** from [github](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-simple-slider/tree/master/css). Include css-styles like in [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/aqJ2PZir). If this doesn't help, seems there is some kind of browser incompatibility. This screenshot was made using Firefox 17.0.9.

Comment: Yeah, it is working fine with firefox. But in chrome it is displayed in the next line. Anyways, thanks a lot